# VueJS2 - Triggering modal component from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

So this one is a bit tricky for me. I have a Sidebar.vue component with a link(Help). I want to trigger my Modal.vue component with different data for every main view eg. Home, About, Contact etc. So whenever I am on Home I want to trigger help modal with hints via that link for Home.vue, when I am on About I want to show hints for About.vue and so on..

My code:

Sidebar.vue

```
<template>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a @click="openHelp">Help</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Sidebar',
    methods: {
        openHelp() {
            this.$emit('help-modal');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Modal.Vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" v-if="open">
        <div class="modal-title">
            <h4>Help</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Modal',

    props: {
        open: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('closed');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    Home
    <modal
      :open="helpOpen"
      @closed="openHelpModal">
       <p>Home Help</p>
        </modal>
  </div>
  <template>
    <sidebar/>
  </template>
</template>
<script>
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Sidebar,
  },
 data() {
   return {
     helpOpen: false,
  }
 }
 methods: {
   openHelpModal() {
     this.helpOpen = !this.helpOpen;
   },
 }
}
</script>
```

I know that vuex would be the best solution but don't have an idea how to approach it. Modal would show only static images with a bit of text for every main view.

Comment: If you use `vue-router` then you [could use](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute) `this.$router.currentRoute.path` in your `Modal.Vue` to decide what info to render. Simple `v-if` would work. You also need to finish your logic to listen to event `<sidebar @help-modal="helpOpen = true" />`

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to simply add a property to the modal component e.g `helpData` and pass the relevant data to this prop in each of the main pages as shown below

Modal.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" v-if="open">
        <div class="modal-title">
            <h4>Help</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Modal',

    props: {
        open: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        helpData: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },

    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('closed');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    Home
    <modal
      :open="helpOpen"
      @closed="openHelpModal"
      :help-data="This is a sample help data for the home view"
    />
  </div>
  <template>
    <sidebar @help-modal="helpOpen = true"/>
  </template>
</template>
<script>
import Sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue';
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Sidebar,
  },
 data() {
   return {
     helpOpen: false,
  }
 }
 methods: {
   openHelpModal() {
     this.helpOpen = !this.helpOpen;
   },
 }
}
</script>
```

As indicated by [@ljubadr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226121/ljubadr), I have included the logic that would open the modal in the sidebar component of `Home.vue`. Also, I would recommend you change the name of the function `openHelpModal` to `closeHelpModal` (seeing as this function will basically close the modal) or `toggleHelpModal` (since from the logic of the function, it toggles the modal state).